# C# XML - Copy an attribute to a child element

Tags: c#

For example I have an XML structure as follws:

```
<element1>
  <element 2 name = "Blah" value = "Something">
    <element 3 name = "Blah" type = "Something">
    <element 3 name = "Woo" type = "Wibble">
      <element 4 name = "Hello">
      <element 4 name = "Goodbye">
      </element4>
    </element3>
  <element2>
</element1>
```

Rough structure guide only. No how would I in C# write an app that copies the value attribute in element 2 and places it in each instance of element 3, but only if it has an element 4 child?

For the commenter who asked for an example:

I wish to loop through the XML document and for each instance of element3 that contains an element4 child, I wish to copy the 'value' attribute in the element2 parent of that element3 and add it to the list of attributes in that element 3. If that makes sense :\

Comment: will you please elaborate well your question with example

Answer (score 3):

Well, I would:

- Load the XML into an `XDocument`
- Find `<element2>` using `doc.Descendants("element2").First()` or `doc.Root.Element("element2")`
- Find the attribute value you'll want to copy, e.g. with `string value = (string) element.Attribute("value");`
- Iterate over all all `<element3>` elements using `doc.Root.Elements("element3")`
- Test each `<element3>` for children with `element.Element("element4") != null`
- Call `element.SetAttributeValue("value", value")` on any appropriate elements.